# I want to show and hide div data via CSS for ebay product listing page

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to show my page at eBay. I have tabs which are working in javascript properly but eBay does not support javascript, so I need to do this via CSS.

```
 <ul class="infotabs">
   <li><a href="" id="tab1" style="background-color:#000">Payment</a></li>
   <li><a href="" id="tab2">Shipping</a></li>
   <li><a href="" id="tab3">Return policy</a></li>
</ul>


 ///////////////////my multiple div//////////////////////

 <div class="contentwraper" id="newboxes1" name="newboxes">
     <h2>Payment</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="contentwraper" id="newboxes2" name="newboxes">
     <h2>Shipment</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="contentwraper" id="newboxes3" name="newboxes">
     <h2>Policy</h2>
 </div>
```

How this can this be done using css?

Comment: It can't be achieved with CSS only because you need an event to change the tab content.

Comment: It **is** possible. You could, for example, check the state of a checkbox with CSS attribute `:checked` - ` input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
}
`

Comment: You can use CSS to set visibility of a div. To actually hide it, you need Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

you can this way, And it doesn't need any javascript
first see [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8HmQ/) 
and consider this expample :

```
<a href="#div1">Div one</a>
<a href="#div2">Div two</a>
<a href="#div3">Div three</a>
<a href="#div4">Div four</a>

<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div one</div>
    <div id="div2">This is div two</div>
    <div id="div3">This is div three</div>
    <div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

and your css

```
#content > div {
    display: none;
}

#content > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

In the HTML the wrapper div (#content) isn't necessary, it's simply to make it easier to specifically target those elements it contains (you could, of course, simply use a class instead).

To add hiding functionality (to hide all, rather than just hide the sibling divs when showing another), unfortunately requires a link to trigger a hash-change (in order to stop the :target selector matching the divs), which in turn requires a link (either in each of the divs to show or elsewhere in the document, either linking elswhere

Comment: thanks @vaibhav its working in local browser but when I put this in ebay there is not working very sad.

Comment: @Attarisoft, i suggest you create another question where you put the code with the proper css that you are uploading on ebay server.
i appreciate if you just do that.

Comment: I posted it please check

Answer (score 0):

I am no CSS guy, so I'll keep this short and point to other folks who are way better at this:

Briefly, the idea is, for example, to check for the state of an `checkbox` element, than apply corresponding styles

**http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/**

**CSS**

```
.to-be-changed {
   color: black;
 }   

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<input type="checkbox">
<p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
```